# black overlay not applied full page

Tags: html, css

blackoverlay effect doesn't apply full background.

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    .black_overlay{display:none;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;z-index:1001;-moz-opacity:0.6;opacity:.60;filter:alpha(opacity=60);}

    .white_content{display:none;position:absolute;top:25%;left:20%;z-index:1002;background:white;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="white_content" name="ppdiv">Test</div>
    <div class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Click here to see my problem** https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uxYL.jpg

But the blackoverlay color not not applied fully. Half page only applied remaining

Copy and paste the following code and save in a html file and check

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <style>
    .black_overlay {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 1001;
      -moz-opacity: 0.6;
      opacity: .60;
      filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    .white_content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 1002;
      background: white;
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function opnpp() {
      $(".white_content").show();
      $(".black_overlay").show();

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="opnpp();" value="Open popup">
  <br>
  <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(First option is consider as your answer)</b>
  <br>
  <br>

  <table border="1px">
    <tr>
      <td>Topic</td>
      <td><span id="section_type" class="flcapz"></span>
      </td>

      <td>Mark</td>
      <td><span id="tot_Mark"></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">Total Question : <span id="tot_Question"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total Answered</td>
      <td><span id="tot_Answered"></span>
      </td>

      <td>Wrong Answer</td>
      <td><span id="wrng_Answered"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Reset Test" onclick="resettest();">

  <div class="question_2" id="q1" style="width:100%;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss1" class="alrdyblock" style="">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id1" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls">First Important Line</span>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>


    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>1.HTML stands for?</b>
    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o1">Home Text Markup Language</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o2">Hyper Text Margin Language</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o3">Home Transfer Markup Language</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="answer">Hyper Text Markup Language</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(1,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>




  <div class="question_2" id="q2" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss2" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id2" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>2. HTML tags are place inside in what?</b>
    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o1">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="answer">&lt;and&gt;</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o2">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o3">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(2,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>




  <div class="question_2" id="q3" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss3" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id3" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>3. tags and text are placed inside which tag?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n3">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n3">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n3">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n3">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(3,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q4" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss4" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id4" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>4. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n4">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n4">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n4">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n4">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(4,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q5" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss5" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id5" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>5. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n5">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n5">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n5">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n5">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(5,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q6" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss6" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id6" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>6. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n6">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n6">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n6">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n6">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(6,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>


  <div class="question_2" id="q7" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss7" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id7" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>7. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n7">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n7">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n7">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n7">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(7,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q8" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss8" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id8" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>8. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n8">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n8">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n8">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n8">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(8,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <div class="white_content" name="ppdiv">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? could you post a snippet to include **all relevant code**?

Comment: Just display the popup

Comment: I don't see a popup in your code? Could you possibly be more specific?

Comment: Please check the code above, jsfiddle not working.

Comment: Rather than using position: absolute, try position:fixed instead

Comment: Updated answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the style of `.black_overlay` to this

```
.black_overlay {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    opacity:.60;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

use the `position: fixed` like yours `.white_overlay`, then specify the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` to 0, then it's done

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <style>
    .black_overlay {
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity:0.6;
        opacity:.60;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    .white_content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 1002;
      background: white;
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function opnpp() {
      $(".white_content").show();
      $(".black_overlay").show();

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="opnpp();" value="Open popup">
  <br>
  <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(First option is consider as your answer)</b>
  <br>
  <br>

  <table border="1px">
    <tr>
      <td>Topic</td>
      <td><span id="section_type" class="flcapz"></span>
      </td>

      <td>Mark</td>
      <td><span id="tot_Mark"></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">Total Question : <span id="tot_Question"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total Answered</td>
      <td><span id="tot_Answered"></span>
      </td>

      <td>Wrong Answer</td>
      <td><span id="wrng_Answered"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Reset Test" onclick="resettest();">

  <div class="question_2" id="q1" style="width:100%;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss1" class="alrdyblock" style="">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id1" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls">First Important Line</span>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>


    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>1.HTML stands for?</b>
    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o1">Home Text Markup Language</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o2">Hyper Text Margin Language</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="o3">Home Transfer Markup Language</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id1" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n1" value="answer">Hyper Text Markup Language</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(1,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>




  <div class="question_2" id="q2" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss2" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id2" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>2. HTML tags are place inside in what?</b>
    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o1">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="answer">&lt;and&gt;</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o2">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id2" class="cmn" type="radio" name="n2" value="o3">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(2,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>




  <div class="question_2" id="q3" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss3" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id3" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>3. tags and text are placed inside which tag?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n3">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n3">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n3">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id3" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n3">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(3,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q4" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss4" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id4" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>4. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n4">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n4">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n4">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id4" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n4">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(4,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q5" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss5" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id5" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>5. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n5">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n5">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n5">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id5" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n5">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(5,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q6" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss6" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id6" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>6. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n6">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n6">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n6">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id6" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n6">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(6,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>


  <div class="question_2" id="q7" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss7" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id7" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>7. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n7">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n7">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n7">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id7" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n7">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(7,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>



  <div class="question_2" id="q8" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div id="ss8" class="alrdyblock">Already Answered</div>
    <div id="q1id8" style="display:none;">
      <span class="allinworldspacls"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="question" style="margin-left: 22px;"><b>8. What is the mening of the below?</b>

    </div>
    <table width="40%" style="margin-left: 24px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i1" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o1" name="n8">Pick</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i2" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o2" name="n8">Dog</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i3" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="o3" name="n8">Deer</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input data-item="i4" data="q1id8" class="cmn" type="radio" value="answer" name="n8">Cow</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <a class="#" onclick="view_ans(8,this);return false;" href="#">Answer/Solution</a>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <div class="white_content" name="ppdiv">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*Note: you use both `position: absolute` and `position: fixed` for your `.white_overlay`, remove the `absolute` one because it's not used

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Having looked at your snippet again, since your page 'scrolls', it would make sense for you to use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute;` This is because the div will then 'scroll with' you, meaning that you wouldn't be able to see the white background behind whilst it is on the screen.

---

## My Version

Here is a sample of a css popup design that you can use. Note that the jquery currently used is there to toggle the visibility of the popup, and no more.

```js
$('.normaltext button').click(function() {
  $('.popuptext').addClass("activepopup");
});

$('.popuptext button').click(function() {
  $('.popuptext').removeClass("activepopup");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.popuptext {
  display: none;
}
.activepopup {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.popuptext button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="normaltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  <button>Open Popup</button>
</div>
<div class="popuptext">This is a popup
  <button>Close Popup</button>
</div>
```